# CMD command from PowerShell with admin priviledges

Tags: powershell, cmd, aws-ssm

I am running a command in PowerShell with parameters-

```
cmd.exe /c 'c:/softwares/agent.exe CustomerId={123456789} ActivationId={123456789} WebServiceUri=https://example.com/agent/'
```

When running the command with admin PowerShell, it works well but not with default permissions.
Since I need to run the command using SSM document, I need to bypass the confirmation prompt and also cannot edit the settings on the machine.

Is there any way I can execute the command with admin permissions and without changing any settings?

Comment: Please perform a search before asking the question.  This is a very commonly asked question and as such has been answered before.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass ?